# Using [UIApplication sharedApplication] to open URL behaving strange

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiapplication

I'm writing an iOS app which is monetized by getting people to sign up to a bookmakers. The bookmaker has offers which change all the time so my idea is to pick out the best offer, and host the link URL on my server. The app will then grab the URL from my server and direct the users to that URL.

The function that I'm using to do the redirecting is:

```
- (IBAction)SignUp:(id)sender {

    NSError *error;
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myserver.com?bookie=offer"];
    NSString *content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
    NSLog(@"%@", content);
    if (content != nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"Doing it");
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:content]];
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"Not Doing it");
    }
}
```

I can see that the correct URL is read from my server, and that the app appears to be "Doing it", but nothing happens.

If I replace the line `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:content]];` with `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.bookie.com/offer"]];` then everything works fine.

I'd really appreciate any pointers, thanks.

Comment: Try logging `content`.

Comment: You should probably be checking if `error` is not nil, not whether the returned string is `nil`. If the `error` is not nil, it'll give you a description of whatever went wrong. Try logging that rather than whether or not the content is nil.

Comment: logging content showed the URL I expected. I didn't check error, there might have been something in there. I've decided to just hit the URL of my server and use a meta refresh HTML tag to redirect to the desired offer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this line actually saves a literal string of whatever is on that URL, you don't need that (based on your question). That would be for parsing data from that page or many other things. You only need the NSURL.

```
NSString *content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
```

So when you save the NSURL on this line

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myserver.com?bookie=offer"];
```

Just use the url later

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

That'll work fine.

Comment: Can review the apple docs on stringWithContentsOfURL here [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSString/stringWithContentsOfURL:encoding:error:)